# Need help with two symbols for Complex Analysis

Tags: math-mode

I cannot find how to write "cis" which is the polar form of complex number, or "Arg" which is short for argument.  Does anybody know these symbols?  Thanks.

Comment: If these are *symbols*, we need to see what they look like. Of course, it would help if you could review the approaches listed in [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: cis should look similar to the symbol cos for cosine, or sin for sine.  Arg should just look like Arg.  The point is that they are functions and need to have input with them.

Comment: You can define your own operators, if not already defined.  I forget the syntax, but at the package level, `\def\Arg{\mathop{\operator@font Arg}\nolimits}`, which is how `\sin` is defined, substituting `Arg` in its place.  If defining it in your document, surround by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\cis{cis}
\DeclareMathOperator\Arg{Arg}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\def\Arg{\mathop{\operator@font Arg}\nolimits}
\def\cis{\mathop{\operator@font cis}\nolimits}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
sin is defined as\\
\meaning\sin

$\Arg x \ne \cis y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `fontenc` package is not needed for the operator definition, but only to properly show the meaning of `\sin`.